# how to create this figure with 3 labels in R? (showing different shades)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

[image]

I wonder how to integrate three variables in one figure as the example in the
attached picture. 
How to realize that the "number of pairs" are denoted by different shades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x=runif(1e5), y=rpois(1e5,20))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x,y)) + stat_bin2d()
```

[image]